# Why are my CSS star layers not aligning properly?

Tags: html, css

I want the Yellow Stars to completely obscure the blue stars

Could anyone help complete this? Or at least point to the right direction?

This is my code:

```css
.star-ratings-css {

  width: 100px;
}
.star-ratings-css-top {
      display: block;
     height: 22px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.star-ratings-css-bottom::before  {
color: #167ac6;
    content: "★★★★★";
    font-size: 22px;
    position: absolute;
}
.star-ratings-css-top::before  {
    color: #f4b414;
    content: "★★★★★";
    font-size: 22px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="star-ratings-css">
  <div class="star-ratings-css-bottom"></div>
  <div class="star-ratings-css-top" style="width: 31%"></div>

</div>
```

It does not work as I would like. What I am doing wrong?

Yellow stars do not completely cover the blue stars.

[image]

Comment: Remove the `height` CSS property on `star-ratings-css-top`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your example:

- The top element is 31% of 100px but the stars have a different width. If you set the width to 50% it will not display 2½ stars!
- You're setting a height of 22px on top element and which is shorter than the actual height of bottom element (22px * line height = ~30px) which is the issue your'e talking about.

You could use `display: inline-block` to make the container stretch to contents i.e. the actual width of five stars. This will make percentage widths match the correct number (or fraction) of stars. And remove the `height: 22px`. The simplified code would look like this:

```css
.star-ratings-css {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.star-ratings-inner {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star-ratings-inner::after {
  color: #f4b414;
  content: "★★★★★";
}

.star-ratings-css::after {
  color: #167ac6;
  content: "★★★★★";
}
```

```html
<div class="star-ratings-css">
  <div class="star-ratings-inner" style="width: 31%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have put it on wordpress, and set the width to 50% then it will not display 2½ stars! https://woovn.com/them-tinh-thanh-pho-vao-form-checkout-cua-woocommerce

Comment: In the direction of Temani Afif I added `white-space: nowrap;` and it worked. thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Just remove  `overflow: hidden;` and it will work like a charm. Below is an example for 4/5.

```css
.star-ratings-css {
  width: 100px;
}
.star-ratings-css-top {
    display: block;
     height: 22px;
    position: relative;
}
.star-ratings-css-bottom::before  {
    color: #167ac6;
    content: "★★★★★";
    font-size: 22px;
    position: absolute;
}
.star-ratings-css-top::before  {
    color: #f4b414;
    content: "★★★★";
    font-size: 22px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="star-ratings-css">
  <div class="star-ratings-css-bottom"></div>
  <div class="star-ratings-css-top" style="width: 31%"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try the "Inspect" feature of the Chrome browser to adjust CSS settings to what you want displayed.

The first two stars were made all yellow with the following changes.

[image]

- Remove: "height: 22px;" from .start-ratings-css-top::before
- Change: style="width: 31%" to style="width: 35%"

Another option to get just two (2) yellow stars is ...

- Remove: "height: 22px;" from .start-reatings-css-top
- Remove: style="width: 31%"
- Change: content: "★★"; for .start-ratings-css-top::before

Comment: FYI all browsers with accessible developer tools have an Inspect feature. It is not unique to Chrome (nor were they the first to have one).

Answer (score 2):

## Star Rating Icons

The code in is overcomplicated and could be easily done with better tags than `<div>`s and can be interactive as well.

### HTML

The two types of tags used in the following demo are:

```
<input id='ID' name='rad' type='radio'>
```

and

```
<label for='ID' class='star'>★</label>
```

There's an `input` and `label` for each star icon, the `ID` of the input is matched by the `label` `[for]` attribute. When an `input/label` pair is setup this way, they are associated so that when one is clicked the other is clicked as well. All `inputs` will be hidden and all `labels` will be styled.

---

### CSS

Each `input` will be followed by the next `label`:

```
<label for='ID3' class='star'>★</label> // 1. User clicks

<input id='ID3' name='rad' type='radio'> // 2. Which puts this as: [name='rad']:checked

<label for='ID4' class='star'>★</label> /* 3. Any labels that occur from this point on
will be styled: ~ .star {color:navy}*/

<input id='ID4' name='rad' type='radio'>

<label for='ID5' class='star'>★</label>
```

So when this ruleset is in CSS:

```
 [name='rad']:checked ~ .star { `color: navy` }
```

it will style the stars in two states: default `color: gold` (on) or `color: navy` (off).

---

### Demo

**Click a star and any stars to the right of it will turn off. Click to the left or right end where there are no stars and all stars will be turned off.**

```css
[name=rad] {
  display: none
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 10vh;
  line-height: 1;
  color: gold;
  background: none;
  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[name=rad]:checked~.star {
  color: navy;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

#s0:checked~.star {
  color: navy;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

[name=rad]+label.star:hover {
  color: cyan;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

[name=rad]+label.star:active {
  color: tomato;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<label for='s0' class='void'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<input id='s0' name='rad' type='radio' value='0'>
<label for='s1' class='star'>&#9733;</label>
<input id='s1' name='rad' type='radio' value='1'>
<label for='s2' class='star'>&#9733;</label>
<input id='s2' name='rad' type='radio' value='2'>
<label for='s3' class='star'>&#9733;</label>
<input id='s3' name='rad' type='radio' value='3'>
<label for='s4' class='star'>&#9733;</label>
<input id='s4' name='rad' type='radio' value='4'>
<label for='s5' class='star'>&#9733;</label>
<input id='s5' name='rad' type='radio' value='5' checked>
<label for='s0' class='void'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **absolute position** for `:before` and `:after` selectors.

```css
.star-ratings-css {
  width: 100px;
}
.star-ratings-css-top {
      display: block;
     height: 22px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.star-ratings-css-bottom::before  {
color: #167ac6;
    content: "★★★★★";
    font-size: 22px;
    position:absolute;top:0;left:8px
}
.star-ratings-css-top::before  {
    color: #f4b414;
    content: "★★★★★";
    font-size: 22px;
    position:absolute;top:-8px;left:0
}
```

```html
<div class="star-ratings-css">
  <div class="star-ratings-css-bottom"></div>
  <div class="star-ratings-css-top" style="width: 31%"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code using one element

```css
.star-ratings-css {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.star-ratings-css::before {
  color: #167ac6;
  content: "★★★★★";
}

.star-ratings-css::after {
  color: #f4b414;
  content: "★★★★★";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: var(--p, 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="star-ratings-css" style="--p:20%;"></div>
<br>
<div class="star-ratings-css" style="--p:50%;"></div>
<br>
<div class="star-ratings-css"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have put it on wordpress, and set the width to 50% then it will not display 2½ stars! https://woovn.com/them-tinh-thanh-pho-vao-form-checkout-cua-woocommerce

Comment: @LêNghĩa updated my answer, you need to add `white-space:nowrap;`

Comment: @LêNghĩa this isn't the code you're using of your website :)